# How to position bootstrap buttons where I want?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Inside this code

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>TraceMySteps</h1>
       <div>
            <div range-slider
                 floor="0"
                 ceiling="19"
                 dragstop="true"
                 ng-model-low="lowerValue"
                 ng-model-high="upperValue"></div>
        </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="right-panel-link" href="#right-panel">Visualizations Panel</button>
</div>
```

I have my `bootstrap` button created. The problem here is that it is positioned on the bottom left of my div. I want to put it on the top-right/center of the div, aligned with my title (`h1`). How do I position it where I want it? I'm new to `bootstrap` so I do not know about these workarounds. Thank you.

Comment: Use position absolute - simple css

Comment: I tried to, I must be doing something wrong because the button hides

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You can use bootstrap's classes to do this.

You can add `pull-right` class to float the button to the right.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="right-panel-link" href="#right-panel">Visualizations Panel</button>
  <h1>TraceMySteps</h1>
  <div>
    <div range-slider floor="0" ceiling="19" dragstop="true" ng-model-low="lowerValue" ng-model-high="upperValue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live example [here](http://www.bootply.com/2JHCPJslHT).

### As per your comments, for more precise control you can do this with absolute positioning instead.

You give the `content` element relative positioning and give the `button` absolute positioning. You can then use any combination of the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties to place it where you would like.

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}
#right-panel-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content">
  <h1>TraceMySteps</h1>
  <div>
    <div range-slider floor="0" ceiling="19" dragstop="true" ng-model-low="lowerValue" ng-model-high="upperValue"></div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="right-panel-link" href="#right-panel">Visualizations Panel</button>
</div>
```

Live example [here](http://www.bootply.com/4KIfkyhSgx).

Comment: This works for now, but isn't there a way to place them in an arbitrary position?

Comment: Yes, you would give the `content` element relative positioning and give absolute positioning to the button. Then you can use top, right, bottom, and/or left CSS properties to position it.

Comment: Btw, `pull-right` is replaced by `float-right` in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 5):

**Making the bootstrap-button inside a div tag**
you can create the bootstrap button inside a div and use align.

Example:

```
<div style="width:350px;" align="center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >edit profile picture</button>
</div>
```